# block special character except underscore(_) and period(.) in username

Tags: javascript, character

I want my user's username consists of letters, numbers, periods and underscores. But what I have below is it blocks all characters even period and underscore. How will I enable letters, numbers, period, and underscore with the code I have below? Please help. Thank you.

```
function blockSpecialChar(e) {
        var k = e.keyCode;
        return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8   || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple replacement for your function based on regular expressions:

```
function blockSpecialChar(e) {
    return /[^A-Za-z0-9._]/.test(e);
}
```

See it working: https://jsfiddle.net/utt3sf6p/

If you want to use keycodes instead of a regular expression, you have to use the correct keycode function `getCharAt()` and change your boolean expression a bit:

```
function blockSpecialChar(e) {
    var k = e.charCodeAt(0);
    return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || (k >= 48 && k <= 57) || (k == 46) || (k == 95));
}
```

See it working: https://jsfiddle.net/wfn37pu6/

**Note:** The examples assume that `e` contains a single character. If `e` is a keyboard event (like `onkeypress`) instead, you have to replace `.test(e)` with `.test(e.key)` and `e.charCodeAt(0)` with `e.key.charCodeAt(0)`.

Comment: This enables all characters even "{}[]//;;" and etc. I only need letters, numbers, period and underscores. Others I want to be blocked or disabled.

Comment: Whoops. Yes, I forgot the `return` statement. Now it's working (see the JSFiddle link).

Comment: It's still the same when I try it :(

Comment: The JSFiddles are working for me. Are you sure that the input argument `e` contains the correct character?

Comment: My input actually look like this `<input type="text" name="username" id="username" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" onkeypress="return blockSpecialChar(event)"  required />`

Comment: It's working now. Thank you so much for your help and patience! :)

Comment: Great you've made it work :) It would be nice if you could mark my answer as accepted if it helped you to solve the problem. For the future I recommend that you also explain in what context the function is used, when asking a question about a specific function.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/
```

Link You can also use the character class \w to replace A-Za-z0-9_
[enter link description here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions.html)

Comment: (A) The requirement is "letters, numbers, periods and underscores", and (B) How would this fit into the OP's function, which is clearly a keyboard event handler?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [Regular Expression](http://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_regexp.asp) to do this.

```
var username = "something123._";
var patt = /([a-z][0-9][\.\_])*/i; /* this is the pattern u want to test */
var result = patt.test(username); /* result = true or false */

if(result == true){
   alert("your username is nice");
}else{
   alert("your username isn't good");
}
```

i'm not sure from my pattern [u can test your patterns Here](https://regex101.com/#javascript)

**EDIT**

for using keycode :

```
$("input").bind("keypress",function(e){
    var patt = /([a-z][0-9][\.\_])*/i; /* this is the pattern u want to test */
    var value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    var result = patt.test(value ); /* result = true or false */
    /* here you can do anything now */
});
```

Comment: *"you have to use Regular Expression"* - Unless you use one of the various possible non-regex methods. How does this fit within the OP's existing keyboard event handler? In any case, your regex matches a letter followed by a digit followed by a full stop or underscore character - the OP doesn't want to restrict the order in which those characters can appear.

Comment: @nnnnnn in this case of his function : `function blockSpecialChar(e) {
        var k = e.keyCode;
        return patt.test(k);
     }`

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="txt">
        <button onclick="fun()">Test</button>
          <script>
             var patt = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_]*$/;
              var ele = document.getElementById("txt");
              function fun() {
                  var value = ele.value;
                  if(patt.test(value))
                      alert("Valid");
                  else
                      alert("Invalid");
              }
          </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple version

```
$('.YourClass').keypress(function(e){
    var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if ("1234567890qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM._".indexOf(chr) < 0)
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the requirement by regexp and keypress event

```
 $("input").keypress(function(e){
    var patt = /^[\w\._]*$/; 
    var value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    $("span").text(patt.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) ));
    return  patt.test(value ); 
  });
```

[SampleCode](http://%20https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GHH1YWN0E8CK)